# Mac Mini Changing Static Routing

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I am a beginner on this.
When I perform a netstat -nr.

[image]

I need to change

```
default    192.168.1.254
default    link#4
```

to

```
default    link#4
default    192.168.1.254
```

What command to swap this sequence?

Comment: The order of those two entries makes no difference. It basically maps the hardware interface to the IP address for that interface. Could you unravel your question one step back -  what are you trying to get done or what is failing?

Comment: link#4 is actually goes to another subnet IP. When I do a ping, it fails to reply only until I remove the first default network hardware. My other Mac mini I don't know why link#4 is the first default and is working well.

Comment: Aah - I missed that. Changing the service order in network prefs would be my first thought.

Comment: Hey yeah! Problem solved using your method!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go to System Preferences -> Network to change it manually, with GUI.

Comment: I can change the ordering from the UI?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try with multiple en0 / en1 / en2 on a Mac OS would be to explicitly set the service order in the network preferences.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25445

> You can’t change the order of virtual private network (VPN)
>   connections because they already take priority over non-VPN
>   connections.
>
> 1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Network.
> 2. Click the Action pop-up menu , then choose Set Service Order.
> 3. Drag services into the order you want.
> 4. Click OK, then click Apply to make the new settings active.